# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while disconnecting call in Android 7.1.1

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat

I am using following code to disconnect the call, it is not disconnecting after android updated to 7.1.1 and I am getting getting : "java.lang.SecurityException: MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission" required exception.

```
 String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
            String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
            String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
            Class<?> telephonyClass;
            Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
            Method telephonyEndCall;
            Object telephonyObject;
            Object serviceManagerObject;
            telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
            telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
            serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
            serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
            Method getService = // getDefaults[29];
                    serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
            Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
            tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
            serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
            IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
            Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
            telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
            telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);
```

I have all the call permission, it is working in marshmallow.

Comment: have u got any solution over it?

Comment: have u got any solution for it, because I am also facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

`InvocationTargetException` is thrown because Reflection wraps any other `Exception` in the underlying method into this class. Try putting the whole code in a try/catch block and printing the stack trace with `e.printStackTrace()`. There should be a "Caused By:" line which will hopefuly point you to the right direction.

**EDIT**:
Alternatively you coud use the `e.getCause()` method to get the underlying `Exception`. `e` here being the catched Exception/Throwable.

Comment: getting : java.lang.SecurityException: MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission required.

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory: you need to declare the `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission in the manifest.

Comment: Yeah I know :-) but it says permission is only granted to system apps

Comment: Yeah I just checked the docs. I don't know what specifically changed in Nougat to require this specific permission though. Can you reproduce the issue on other phones running N?